# splinter Python Phantomjs crashes sometime

Tags: python, phantomjs, splinter

I am getting this error while running this code.I am using splinter phantomjs. sometimes it works correctly but sometimes it shows some error.

```
Error:
 raised unexpected: BadStatusLine("''",)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/synerzip/forestway/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
        R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/synerzip/forestway/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
        return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/synerzip/forestway/app/services/connection.py", line 121, in find_connection_for_company
        self.browser.find_by_css("img.entity-img").click()
      File "/home/synerzip/forestway/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/__init__.py", line 539, in click
        self._element.click()
      File "/home/synerzip/forestway/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 74, in click
        self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
      File "/home/synerzip/forestway/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 457, in _execute
        return self._parent.execute(command, params)
      File "/home/synerzip/forestway/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 231, in execute
        response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
      File "/home/synerzip/forestway/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 395, in execute
        return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
      File "/home/synerzip/forestway/flask/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 463, in _request
        resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
        response = self._open(req, data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
        '_open', req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
        result = func(*args)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1214, in http_open
        return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPConnection, req)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1187, in do_open
        r = h.getresponse(buffering=True)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1051, in getresponse
        response.begin()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 415, in begin
        version, status, reason = self._read`enter code here`_status()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 379, in _read_status
        raise BadStatusLine(line)
    BadStatusLine: ''
```

Comment: What version of PhantomJS are you using?